# Find the longest sequence of "1" in a SubList

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence

I'm trying to return the **sublist(s) with the longest sequence of 1**, although my code is working in a majority of cases, there are exceptions that I don't understand .

**Example:**

```
M1 = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
      {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};

MaximalBy[Composition[Max, Cases[a : {1 ..} :> Length[a]], Split]][M1]
```

**Output :**

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

However in this example I want my code to return : `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`

**Does someone have a solution to overcome these exceptions ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the canonical order of expressions. Even though `-∞ < 4` is true, `Order[-∞, 4]` is `-1`. To avoid this you could write:

```
Composition[Max, Append[0], Cases[a : {1 ..} :> Length[a]], Split]
```